# Django keep logged in lost when going outside to paypal payment

Tags: python, django, paypal

I'm kind of new to django, I'm having an issue to keep the logged in user still logged in after he made a payment via PayPal.

So, the user purchases something on my platform via PayPal payment, he is redirected to PayPal (currently to sandbox PayPal domain), PayPal executes the payment and redirects the user back to my platform using redirect_url I'm generating when sending the payment requests json to PayPal api.

After the user is redirected back to my platform he is not logged in anymore.

For example, in another scenario, lets say the user logged in and closed the browser, when they reopen the platform again he is still logged in.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a django token (there are other ways but this is easiest) and store it on the browser. Then send this with all requests to identify the user. [I have linked an excellent tutorial for this](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/how-to-implement-token-authentication-with-django-rest-framework/)

Also an [older tutorial](http://www.supernifty.org/articles/oreilly-django-paypal-store/paypal-django.html) explaining the mechanism of how to handle transactions, just for reference. (Code maybe outdated but the idea remains valid)

Comment: PayPal redirects back to my platform, I cannot send token when redirects back from there. its happen automatic after execute paymnet.

Comment: [Read this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Basically you use this pass all the variables you will need to record the transaction in yur backend.You user auth token can be one of them. Or you can save it as a local variable in the browser (cookies) and access it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED, needed to add SESSION_COOKIE_NAME with my domain name in settings.py file